# Does wp post delete also delete metadata associated with posts?

Tags: wp-cli

say this:

```
wp post delete --force $(wp post list --post_type=product --format=ids)
```

I found out that it's far more fast and performant than deleting posts from admin.

But I was wandering: any differences between the cli and admin ways? For example, will that cli command also delete metadata associated with deleted posts?

Comment: They both call the same functions internally, but one way to test this is to just do it and check if the post meta is still present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes. However, if you run into an issue like custom fields or media hanging around, you could use:

```
wp post meta delete
```